# Unity and IServiceProvider on Prism for WPF

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a WPF Prism application with Unity container.
I would like to add the Serilog logging service.
So I override RegisterTypes as follows:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
            
  containerRegistry.RegisterServices(serviceCollection =>
        serviceCollection.AddLogging(logbuilder => logbuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true)));
}
```

I have following Nuget packages installed:

- Prism.Core
- Prism.Unity
- Prism.Unity.Extensions
- Prism.Wpf

When resolving het MainWindow type from the container I get the error *InvalidOperationException: No public constructor is available for type System.IServiceProvider*

Related information:

- working solution for Prism Xamarin Forms and Dryloc or Unity: [DryIoc and IServiceProvider on Prism for Xamarin.Forms (DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078277/dryioc-and-iserviceprovider-on-prism-for-xamarin-forms-dryioc-microsoft-depende)
- https://github.com/augustoproiete/prism-logging-serilog/issues/3
- [.net5.0 PRISM WPF application, how to use Microsoft.Exensions.Logging with Serilog as provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69269882/net5-0-prism-wpf-application-how-to-use-microsoft-exensions-logging-with-seril)

I can get it to work when I follow the implementation documented in https://www.andicode.com/prism/wpf/logging/2021/05/21/Logging-In-Prism.html
but this is not the same methodology as for Prism Xamarin Forms and Dryloc or Unity.

What is the reason for the difference between WPF and Xamarin Forms?